How to declare a struct with fields at specific offsets in C++?
I have a struct that's memory-read from another program. As such I only know specific fields and not the entire layout.
I currently declare the struct by calculating the paddings in between known members, as such:
struct ForeignType_t
{
    void* Field1;   // [+0]
    char  PAD1[24];
    void* Field2;   // [+32]
    char  PAD2[512];
    void* Field3;   // [+552]
}

(This example is using 64 bit pointers. Alignment can also be ignored for the following examples.)
This syntax requires me to manually calculate the offsets between each member.
I've already tried just calculating the paddings with a macro taking the previous and the next offset, however this is still ugly.
Ideally there would be a syntax such as this:
struct ForeignType_t
{
    [[offset(0)]]
    void* Field1;   // [+0]
    [[offset(32)]]
    void* Field2;   // [+32]
    [[offset(552)]]
    void* Field3;   // [+552]
}

I've been unsuccessful at finding anything like it.
The closest I've come was recreating this myself via Macros and creating effectively "getter" functions, that would reinterpret a buffer member and read from its index.
#define OFFSET(offset, type, name) inline type name()                         \
                                    {                                         \
                                        return *(type*)(&this->Data[offset]); \
                                    }

struct ForeignType_t
{
    char Data[560];
    
    OFFSET(0, void*, Field1)
    OFFSET(32, void*, Field2)
    OFFSET(552, void*, Field3)
}


This implementation is almost perfect. It is easy to read and declare, however has the downside that it is not possible to easily debug this and accessing a field is a function access. foreignType.Field(); vs foreignType.Field;
Is there any other way of achieving a declaration like this without the downsides?

You can use a struct that only contains a char array to store the data, and then use another class(a view class) with reference members to access the fields. Something like struct ForeignTypeView_t{ForeignType_t& f; void*& Field2; ForeignTypeView_t(ForeignType_t& f):f(f), Field2((void*&)(f.Data[32])){}};

managing "by hand" the inner memory can be a solution but be careful of initialization/deletion/alignment of data. As pointed in the comments, this code is UB. It can be made cleaner but It does not seem the main goal (which I don't know at this point).

This is not allowed by C++ standard. You can achieve this by using compiler specific features like #pragma pack(, but this is not recommended way. Please specify you target platforms and actual reason you think you need this (there are alternatives for some scenerios).

Why would this not be allowed by the C++ standard? #pragma pack is something else entirely. Target platform is windows, but is not relevant. And the reason as already mentioned in the question body is that I am mapping a foreign struct of which I only know fields at given offsets, therefore when declaring it I want to avoid having to manually calculate the space in between. I already explained this in the question. If you have an alternative, please provide it. That's what I asked for.

"that it is not possible to easily debug this" you might write custom visualizer (natvis) for debugger.

The final solution I've come up with is using anonymous unions & structs to reinterpret the char Data[#] member.
/* helper macros for unique padding members */
#define STRMERGE_INNER(x, y) x ## y
#define STRMERGE(x, y) STRMERGE_INNER(x, y)

#define OFFSET(offset, type, name) struct {                                    \
                                        char STRMERGE(____, __LINE__)[offset]; \
                                        type name;                             \
                                    };

struct ForeignType_t
{
    union {
        char Data[560];
    
        void* Field1; /* First member has to be normally declared, explanation below. */
        OFFSET(32, void*, Field2)
        OFFSET(552, void*, Field3)
    }
}


The Data member is not actually necessary, as the size is based on the biggest offset + its typesize.
The first member (in this case) is at offset 0 therefore it must be declared as normal, because char PAD[0]; is not valid.
The nested union is still a bit ugly and so is the offset 0 member. Other than that, this fulfills my requirements:

Simple declaration.
Debuggable in the Visual Studio watch window.
Doesn't require a function invocation to access.


This solution is forbidden by the language. Only 1 union member is allowed to be active at once. The last union member to be written to is the only one you are allowed to read from. For example, that means that when you write to Field2 you are no longer allowed to read from Field1 or Field3.

It's undefined behaviour (normally) but most compilers implement it as a normal access. Since this is not a locally declared/constructed type, but instead read from another processes memory and simply interpreted as such, the fields are accessible and contain valid data.

I was going to comment about the UB and then stopped doing so when I noticed the tag [tag:reverse-engineering].

You could solve your problem by using the first approach of using arrays of bytes as padding, but asking the compiler to calculate their size for you.
Using templates or constexpr, you can write compile-time types or functions that calculates each padding sizes from a list of desired offsets.
In the following example the type padding_calculator_t is defined with a list of desired offsets, and provides a templated padding member which returns the type needed for each padding members.
Note that C++ does not allow for 0 sized arrays, so padding data members of size 0 have to be excluded. But certain compilers do support it as an extension, in which case you could leave them in.
https://godbolt.org/z/KPfjd3YMr
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// T : The type of the members
// S : The offset of each member
template<class T, std::size_t ... S>
struct padding_calculator_t
{
    // Get the desired offset of the Nth member (excluding the first unpadded member)
    template<std::size_t Index>
    static constexpr std::size_t offsetOfMember()
    {
        static_assert(Index < sizeof...(S));
        constexpr std::size_t offsets[] = {S...};
        return offsets[Index];
    }

    // Calculate the number of bytes between the end of the previous data member
    //  and the start of the current member to provide the correct offset
    template<std::size_t Index>
    static constexpr std::size_t calculatePadding()
    {
        if constexpr (Index == 0) {
            return offsetOfMember<Index>();
        }
        else {
            return offsetOfMember<Index>() - offsetOfMember<Index - 1>() - sizeof(T);
        }
    }
    
    template<std::size_t Index>
    using padding = std::byte[calculatePadding<Index>()];
};

struct ForeignType_t
{
    using padding_t = padding_calculator_t<void*, 0, 32, 552>;

    // Don't define padding objects when the padding is zero, C++ doesn't allow 0 sized arrays
    // padding_t::padding<0> PAD0;
    void* Field1;
    padding_t::padding<1> PAD1;
    void* Field2;
    padding_t::padding<2> PAD2;
    void* Field3;
};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << 
        "sizeof(void*) : " << sizeof(void*) << '\n' <<
        "Field1 : " << offsetof(ForeignType_t, Field1) << '\n' <<
        "Field2 : " << offsetof(ForeignType_t, Field2) << '\n' <<
        "Field3 : " << offsetof(ForeignType_t, Field3) << '\n';
}

Possible output :
sizeof(void*) : 8
Field1 : 0
Field2 : 32
Field3 : 552

